# Copy a value from one sheet to another and then copy result back to same sheet in different column

Tags: vba, excel

I apologise for the ambiguity in the question/statement but its easier to explain my issue.

I have a tool that I use to process some data in one sheet of my workbook (sheet1). And a data sheet that provides that data (sheet2)

Basically I want to take each value from `Y2:LastRow` of the datasheet (sheet2) run that value through the tool in sheet1 then copy that result and paste it into the same row but a different column (AQ to be exact).

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
With Worksheets("DataSheet")

LastRow = .Range("Y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    For Each cell In Worksheets("DataSheet").Range(Cells(LastRow, 25), Cells(1, 25))

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Conversion Tool").Range("A1").Value = cell
    Sheet1.Range("F14").Copy
    Sheet2.Range(Cells(LastRow, 43), Cells(2, 43)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    Next
End With
```

However, with this is pastes the value into all cells of that column. I know that there is probably some basic fix but I'm still getting to grips with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Record steps as macro view source.

Comment: Sheet2 = "DataSheet"?

Comment: Yes sheet 2 is datasheet. And I would xQbert but the amount of rows changes depending on the data.

Comment: Hi Matt I think you'll want to replace your current Paste Special line of code with something like `cell.Offset(0,18).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)` ( I think column AQ is 18 to the right of Y -might want to test that). Hope that helps

Comment: @maxhob17 thanks for that, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
With Worksheets("DataSheet")    
    LastRow = .Range("Y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each Cell In .Range(Cells(LastRow, 25), Cells(1, 25))
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Conversion Tool").Range("A1").Value = Cell
        Sheet1.Range("F14").Copy
        .Range("AQ" & Cell.Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next

End With
```

It takes the row from the cell you copied and enters the new value in same row but column `AQ`.

Comment: you could clean your code a little, since you are inside the `With Worksheets("DataSheet")` you can modify your `For` syntax to `For Each Cell In .Range(Cells(LastRow, 25), Cells(1, 25))`.